# Does librdkafka and confluent-kafka-go support connecting to a kafka broker via an HTTP proxy with HTTP CONNECT?

Tags: apache-kafka, librdkafka, confluent-kafka-go

I have a kafka producer written in Go using the confluent-kafka-go bindings.

I want my kafka producer to establish a connection to a kafka broker that is behind an HTTP proxy that supports HTTP CONNECT tunneling.

Does librdkafka support this?  Does confluent-kafka-go support this?  If yes, please point me to the relevant documentation or provide a code snippet illustrating how this is done.

If it is not supported, how hard would be it be to add support?

Answer (score 2):

These clients only use Kafka TCP protocol; they don't perform content negotiation or establish a connection with an HTTP CONNECT method.

If you want to use HTTP protocol, you'll need to use an HTTP client

Comment: thanks, that was my impression from looking through the docs and the code